# How do I add resources to a class which has ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

A problem appears (**x:Key attribute required**) when I add: `<s:RsuSensorVisible x:Key="RsuSensorLocalVisible"/>` in my code. The code is posted below and also a picture attached. It seems that they cancel each other. If I remove`<s:RsuSensorVisible x:Key="RsuSensorLocalVisible"/>` works perfect. Some solution?

```
public class RsuSensorVisible : IValueConverter
                {
                    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                    {
                        //string stringValue = ((ContentControl)value).Content;
                        var stringValue = value as string;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                        {
                            return stringValue == "RSU" ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
                        }
                        return Visibility.Visible;
                    }

                    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }
                }

    <Window.Resources>
           <s:RsuSensorVisible x:Key="RsuSensorLocalVisible"/> 
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/DesignerItem.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ToolboxItem.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Toolbox.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Connection.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Stencils/FlowChartStencils.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Stencils/ShapeStencils.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Stencils/SymbolStencils.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Window.Resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the RsuSensorVisible variable inside the ResourceDictionary declaration and the problem will go away. The content of the Window.Resources element must be a ResourceDictionary.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/DesignerItem.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ToolboxItem.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Toolbox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Connection.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Stencils/FlowChartStencils.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Stencils/ShapeStencils.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Stencils/SymbolStencils.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <s:RsuSensorVisible x:Key="RsuSensorLocalVisible"/> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so i'll post an answer.

Have you tried putting your  `<s:RsuSensorVisible x:Key="RsuSensorLocalVisible"/>` inside ResourceDictionary? Or maybe, try to give `x:Key` attribute to your ResourceDictionary. It looks like that's the problem

Comment: RsuSensorVisible variable inside the ResourceDictionary declaration solved the problem, X:key attribute to ResourceDictonary is not working